# Add an Image in an iText PDF document in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, itext

I am trying to add an image in my iText PDF document in Android Studio, with Java, but it always shows the error *NullPointerException*.

The codes i've trying are:

1.

```
try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("res/drawable/logo.png");
        Bitmap bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmapA.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        return image;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2.

```
try {
        Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
        BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
        Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        return image;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3.

```
try {
        Drawable d = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
        BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
        Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        return image;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

4.

```
try {
        Image image = Image.getInstance("res/drawable/logo.png");
        return image;
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

..and no one of those codes are working. Always the same error, not founding the resource.

My question is, can I add an image to an iText doc? How can I do this?

Ps. I'm using iText5 (*implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with some small changes. I'll let it here if anyone else is needing it.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    Image img = null;
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        img = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then, this `img` you can add to your PDF file in iText.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
 ImageData logo = ImageDataFactory.create(stream.toByteArray());
 document.add(new Image(logo));
```